# Jenkins hanged and not starting after a service restart

Tags: jenkins

After Jenkins restart we have the below error, Jenkins user has the correct permission and the plugin matrix-auth and matrix-project exist not sure what happened

version 2.7.4

````
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /jenkins/config.xml
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:45)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1009)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:877)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /jenkins/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:2785)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$700(Jenkins.java:324)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:2803)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:998)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 8
version             : not available```


Please help
````

Comment: Looks like it didn't hang, since it gave you a stack dump including a very useful line near the top.  Does `/jenkins/config.xml` exist?

Comment: Yes, and jenkins account can read it

Comment: ```[jenkins@jenkins-01 /jenkins]$ ls -lart | grep config.xml```
```-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins  poppers     63290 Apr  8 07:32 config.xml```

Comment: `at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)`.  Make sure the file is valid XML, and try the standard tricks if you're convinced that it's valid.